# Error TF51535 adding custom field to Azure DevOps via Logic App and the REST API

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-devops-rest-api

I am writing a set of Logic Apps which will create a custom work item type (RAID), several custom fields and several custom queries to support dashboards. I am using the "Send an HTTP request to Azure DevOps" connector. Most of my calls are working as expected (e.g. List Fields, Create Work Item Type) but I'm struggling with [Add Custom Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/fields/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1). The POST is returning a status code 400 and the error is `"TF51535: Cannot find field <referenceName>"`.

Here is the ADD Field request for a field named "Impact", which is a multiline text field (html) and the expected referenceName would be "Custom.Impact":

[Connector Inputs img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkj6V.png)

[Connector Outputs img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZciI.png)

Raw Inputs:

```
{
   "method": "post",
   "queries": {
      "account": "McKDevOps"
   },
   "path": "/httprequest",
   "host": {
      "connection": {
         "name": "/subscriptions/f1ba7a1c-8591-4fa3-a3ca-6d80be589c0b/resourceGroups/AutomationTest/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/visualstudioteamservices"
       }
   },
   "body": {
       "Body": "{\n \"name\": \"Impact\",\n \"referenceName\": \"Custom.Impact\",\n \"type\": \"html\",\n \"description\": \"Impact description for RAID items (Risks, Issues, Decisions)\"\n}",
   "Headers": {
       "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "Method": "POST",
    "Uri": "_apis/work/processes/dfcfbe38-23af-4794-957e-58d21b0f3d96/workItemTypes/McKAgilev1.RAID/fields?api-version=6.1-preview.2"
}
```

Raw Outputs:

```
{
"statusCode": 400,
"headers": {
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "x-ms-request-id": "e882a646-1d7c-4d2b-9e54-8b332641f866",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
    "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
    "Set-Cookie": "ARRAffinity=0102e146bf02da3054822d4acfdabff925d548924e264227d7e2dd7a4eef2676;Path=/;HttpOnly;Secure;Domain=vsts-eus.azconn-eus-01.p.azurewebsites.net,ARRAffinitySameSite=0102e146bf02da3054822d4acfdabff925d548924e264227d7e2dd7a4eef2676;Path=/;HttpOnly;SameSite=None;Secure;Domain=vsts-eus.azconn-eus-01.p.azurewebsites.net",
    "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
    "Date": "Tue, 22 Jun 2021 22:29:19 GMT",
    "Content-Length": "1170",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Expires": "-1"
},
"body": {
    "status": 400,
    "message": "TF51535: Cannot find field Custom.Impact.\r\nAzure DevOps ActivityId: 3662996d-ea0f-49ab-a9a5-a8d9f1835826\r\nDetails: {\"$id\":\"1\",\"innerException\":null,\"message\":\"TF51535: Cannot find field Custom.Impact.\",\"typeName\":\"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.WorkItemTrackingFieldDefinitionNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server\",\"typeKey\":\"WorkItemTrackingFieldDefinitionNotFoundException\",\"errorCode\":0,\"eventId\":3200}\r\nclientRequestId: e882a646-1d7c-4d2b-9e54-8b332641f866",
    "error": {
        "message": "TF51535: Cannot find field Custom.Impact.\r\nAzure DevOps ActivityId: 3662996d-ea0f-49ab-a9a5-a8d9f1835826\r\nDetails: {\"$id\":\"1\",\"innerException\":null,\"message\":\"TF51535: Cannot find field Custom.Impact.\",\"typeName\":\"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server.Metadata.WorkItemTrackingFieldDefinitionNotFoundException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server\",\"typeKey\":\"WorkItemTrackingFieldDefinitionNotFoundException\",\"errorCode\":0,\"eventId\":3200}"
    },
    "source": "vsts-eus.azconn-eus-01.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have learned that it is necessary to [Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/fields/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) a custom field using the CREATE FIELD api before one can [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/processes/fields/add?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) it to a work item.